# Exporting measurement id from Google Analytics v4

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Google automatically created corresponding v4 properties when migrating from Universal analytics.

Is there any way to export all properties? I need to get an overview of measurement ids for all domains for a reference.

I went through whole GA interface and I don't seem to find Export function. I haven't checked API. That would be the last resort..

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that you can use old UA measurement ids with GA4..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).